# using multiple sep arguments in a character string

Tags: r, paste

I have a data frame (dates) that looks like this:

```
year month start end
2000    06    01  10
2000    06    11  20
2000    06    21  30
```

I want to create a vector of character strings (one for each row in the data frame) so that each date follows this format:

year month start-end (first row would be 2000 06 01-10).

I've tried using a for loop with the paste function:

```
titles <- character()
for (i in 1:nrow(dates)){
  titles[i] <- paste(dates[i, 1], dates[i,2], dates[i,3], dates[i,4])
}

> titles
[1] "2000 06 01 10" "2000 06 11 20" "2000 06 21 30"
```

but I can't figure out how to replace the last space with a dash. Is there a way to coerce the paste function into doing this or is there another function I can use?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your solution, if you just replace

```
paste(dates[i, 1], dates[i,2], dates[i,3], dates[i,4])
```

with

```
paste(dates[i, 1], dates[i,2], paste(dates[i,3], dates[i,4], sep = "-"))
```

that should work already. This just nests the "-" separating paste within the " " separating paste (default of paste is " ").

A more elegant one-liner would be to use apply:

```
apply(dates, 1, function(row)paste(row[1], row[2], paste(row[3], row[4], sep = "-")))
[1] "2000 06 01-10" "2000 06 11-20" "2000 06 21-30"
```

Comment: `paste` is vectorized, so there's no reason to loop through each row.

Comment: @avid_useR it only works vectorized over columns, not rows, or?

Comment: when you write something like `paste(year, month)`, the entire `year` and `month` columns are passed on through `paste`, so `paste` was only called once, vs if you loop through each element, the `paste` function is being called for _each element_. So it's 1 call vs n calls (n = # of elements). As a result, the former is much faster.

Comment: All you need to write is `with(df, paste(paste(year, month, start, sep = " "), end, sep = "-"))`, which is basically JasonAizkalns's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a loop, you may want to consider:

```
df$titles <- with(df, paste(year, month, start, end, sep = "-"))
df
#   year month start end        titles
# 1 2000    06    01  10 2000-06-01-10
# 2 2000    06    11  20 2000-06-11-20
# 3 2000    06    21  30 2000-06-21-30
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `unite` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  unite("new_date", year:end, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(new_date = sub("\\s(\\d+)$", "-\\1", new_date))
```

or with two `unite`'s:

```
df %>%
  unite("temp_date", year:start, sep = " ") %>%
  unite("new_date", temp_date, end, sep = "-")
```

**Output:**

```
      new_date
1  2000 6 1-10
2 2000 6 11-20
3 2000 6 21-30
```